# How to center text from following element under an image

Tags: html, css

I have two `<div>`s, where image is present in one and the text is present in another.

Now, I want to make sure that text must come below the image in the centre. If I have one `<div>` it would be easy but I'm supposed to use the existing structure which contains separate `<div>`s for text and image.

For now, I have written CSS like this for the text under the `<div class="sidebyside_pera">`

```
.sidebyside_pera p {
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:-70px;
    margin-top:110px;
}
```

Below is the CSS for the *image* `<div class="sidebyside_image">`

```
.sidebyside_new {
    float:left;
}
```

The above CSS works fine for an image of fixed pre-set size. How can I set the CSS for images of variables images so that text comes under the image in the centre.

Here is my current structure:

```
<div class="sidebyside_new">
    <img src="<%=imageLink %>" alt="<%=altText %>" width="<%=imgwidth %>" height="<%=imgheight %>" />
</div>
<div class="sidebyside_pera">
   <p> <%=description %> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please post a fiddle with also your html?

Comment: Hi Benderr, I have added the div structure, thanks Balaji

Comment: I have added an image of the div structure

Comment: what is that, a screen for ants?! :D to properly format your code, you just needed to add a return between "text" and "code".

Comment: NOOOOOOOOO.. don't add images to show code.. just try to format it correctly.. it shouldn't be that hard.. leave an empty line before putting the code.. and your code should have at least 4 spaces indentation..

Comment: couldnt u copy that text and paste it here?

Comment: sorry will do that now

Comment: In case you don't know fiddle.. try to show it here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: <div class="sidebyside_new">
    <img src="<%=imageLink %>" alt="<%=altText %>" width="<%=imgwidth %>" height="<%=imgheight %>" />
</div>div structure for text
<div class="sidebyside_pera">
    <p>
        <%=description %>
    </p>
</div>

Comment: I'm not going to edit it until you'll get it right :) Just be honest.. does this preview looks nice to you?!

Comment: sorry Lipis, I have done that atlast

Comment: Mr. AndyB did it for you.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping the divs (one with the image and one with the text) in another div should work.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/VVQxZ/

Comment: Hi PaulvdDool, my problem is Im not supposed to put one more div called container as Im using the existing div structure which is being used by others, if it is the only choice, will follow this, thanks for your help

Comment: If you HAVE to use two different divs for text and image I don't see how it could work without using any Javascript. I'm not a javascript guru so I'm not able to help with that.